# CSS/JS Problems IE7 Suggestions

Tags: css

I have been having some serious issues trying to get this web page I have been working on working correctly with IE7 (ff/chrome/safari/ie8 all work fine).  I have corrected all HTML and CSS issues, but it still does not render the same in IE7.  I have been working on this for months, and was wondering if the community could give me some help:

http://victoriakwasinski.com/

Thanks.

Comment: If I switch to IE 7 Compatability mode it tells me to upgrade to IE 8 or use another browser.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not work like IE7 compatibility mode which doesn't work like IE7 which doesn't work like IE6 and none of them work like other far more modern browsers.

Specifically, what's the problem?

Also, validate your page for those lists of HTML and some serious CSS errors.

Comment: IE7 renders everything to the right a bit, while all of the other browsers show things centered.

Comment: what do you mean, lists of HTML?  what css errors? i validated through some of the web pages - suggestions on finding the css errors?

Comment: thanks, fixed the html errors, but still not working in IE7.... all of the CSS errors are from a library (dojo) i am using - not sure they are contributing...